# Using VB.net IF statement with SQL value

Tags: sql, vb.net

I am trying to use an `IF` statement to do a certain action if my SQL value is greater than 1.

However when I run the below code, it returns an error.

> Operator '>' is not defined for types 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand' and 'Integer'.

Here is the code:

```
Using cmdb = New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO AdditionalDaisyCodes (AddCode) VALUES (@AddCode)", con)
  con.Open()
  cmdb.ExecuteNonQuery()
  con.Close()

  If cmdb > 1 Then

    MessageBox.Show("Duplicate Codes Exist!", "Indigo Billing", _
    MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)

  Else
  End If
End Using
```

Can anybody help with the correct syntax?

Comment: `ExecuteNonQuery()` is never going to be greater than 1 - all you're doing is inserting a single row, and you're not even defining the value to be passed in via the parameter you use in the query string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this

```
   int result=cmdb.ExecuteNonQuery();
if result > 1 then
//code here
else
end if
```

Comment: @user3580480! actually result will be returned by ExecuteNonQuery() instead of SQLCommand object.

Answer (score 1):

You have a bigger problem than just a syntax error.  Based on your posted code, it looks like you want to inform the user that duplicate codes exist.  Since you have an `Else`, I'm going to make a guess and say that if duplicate codes aren't found, you want the insertion made.

Currently the number of rows affected by `ExecuteNonQuery()` will **never** be greater than 1.  In addition, in your posted code you never assign a value to the `@AddCode` parameter - if the `AddCode` column cannot be null, that could cause an error.

What you probably want to do is to check to see if the code exists, and if not then add it.  Something like this would do the trick:

```
Using cmdb = New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM AdditionalDaisyCodes WHERE AddCode = @AddCode", con)
    con.Open()

    cmdb.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AddCode", txtAddCode.Text)
    Dim reader As SqlDataReader = cmdb.ExecuteReader()

    If reader.HasRows Then
        MessageBox.Show("Duplicate Codes Exist!", "Indigo Billing", _
MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)

    Else
        cmdb.CommandText = "INSERT INTO AdditionalDaisyCodes(AddCode) Values(@AddCode)"
        cmdb.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AddCode", txtAddCode.Text)
        cmdb.ExecuteNonQuery()

    End If

    con.Close()
End Using
```

`txtAddCode.Text` in the above example is assuming the code is coming from a `TextBox` named `txtAddCode`.  First it checks to see if the code is already in the table by running a SELECT query restrained by a WHERE clause.  If the returned `SqlDataReader` has rows, then that code is already in the table and the message box is displayed.

If the `SqlDataReader` does not have rows, then the code is not in the table and `cmdb` is reused to do the insert.

Also note that you can put the `SqlConnection` in a `Using` block as well, eliminating the need to call `Close()` on the connection explicitly.